# How to properly mock a function that instantiates a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, class-variables

I have something like this in my source file

```
# code.py

def some_func():
    # doing some connections and stuff
    return {'someKey': 'someVal'}


class ClassToTest:

    var = some_func()
```

My test file looks like this... I am trying to mock `some_func` as I want to avoid creating connections.

```
# test_code.py

from src.code import ClassToTest


def mock_function():
    return {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"}


class Test_Code(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('src.code.some_func', new=mock_function)
    def test_ClassToTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(ClassToTest.var, {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"})
```

But this doesn't work. On the other hand if `var` is an instant variable mock works fine. I guess this is due to class variables getting initialized during imports. How do I properly mock `some_func` before `var` even gets initialized?

Comment: What if you do the import inside of the patched function?

Comment: You mean inside `test_ClassToTest`? That doesn't work either.

Comment: Mm, I guess you can't patch if you haven't imported it yet.  My take is that you might want to reconsider having that connection logic happen at class initialization time (and therefore at import time), and use something like a singleton pattern instead.

Comment: Don't do "some connections and stuff" at import time.  It makes testing the code difficult, as you're seeing.

Comment: Agreed,  It's existing code, I am just writing some tests.

Comment: You should write the tests and the code at the same time, which helps you to develop the code in a testable way. It's not much point to write some tests to cover code which already exists and can't be changed - that's sort of missing the point of testing.

Comment: *use dependency injection*

Answer (score 0):

When you imported `code.py`, there is no active patch yet, so when `ClassToTest.var` was initialized, it used the original `some_func`. Only then would the patch for `src.code.some_func` would take effect which obviously is too late now.

### Solution 1

What you can do is to patch `some_func` and then reload `code.py` so that it re-initializes the `ClassToTest` including its attribute `var`. Thus since we already have an active patch by the time we reload `code.py`, then `ClassToTest.var` would be set with the patched value.

- But we can't do it if both the class and the patched function lives in the same file, so to make it testable move `some_func` to another file and then just import it.

**src/code.py**

```
from src.other import some_func


class ClassToTest:
    var = some_func()
```

**src/other.py**

```
def some_func():
    # doing some connections and stuff
    return {'realKey': 'realValue'}
```

**test_code.py**

```
from importlib import reload
import sys
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from src.code import ClassToTest  # This will always refer to the unpatched version


def mock_function():
    return {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"}


class Test_Code(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_real_first(self):
        self.assertEqual(ClassToTest.var, {"realKey": "realValue"})

    @mock.patch('src.other.some_func', new=mock_function)
    def test_mock_then_reload(self):
        # Option 1:
        # import src
        # reload(src.code)

        # Option 2
        reload(sys.modules['src.code'])

        from src.code import ClassToTest  # This will be the patched version
        self.assertEqual(ClassToTest.var, {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"})

    def test_real_last(self):
        self.assertEqual(ClassToTest.var, {"realKey": "realValue"})
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q 
...                                                                                           [100%]
3 passed in 0.04s
```

### Solution 2

If you don't want the real `some_func` to be ever called during test, then just reloading isn't enough. What needs to be done is to never import the file containing `ClassToTest` nor any file that would import it indirectly. Only import it **once an active patch for `some_func` is already established**.

```
from importlib import reload
import sys
import unittest
from unittest import mock

# from src.code import ClassToTest  # Remove this import!!!


def mock_function():
    return {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"}


class Test_Code(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('src.other.some_func', new=mock_function)
    def test_mock_then_reload(self):
        from src.code import ClassToTest  # Move the import here once the patch has taken effect already
        self.assertEqual(ClassToTest.var, {"someOtherKey": "someOtherValue"})
```

Comment: **Solution 1** is broken because the unpatched code is still run during the test - _"doing some connections and stuff"_ will either fail due to lack of configuration/credentials, or worse it will accidentally succeed in contacting to a real db during test. You have to be very careful to stub out any access to configuration from filesystem, environment variable, default arguments etc here. **Solution 2** is broken because it has to modify the code under test, and if that is an option at all there are _much_ better ways to restructure the code which don't require delaying the import in test.